# Show Lebesgue integral is finite

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $h\in L^2(\mathbb R)$. Show $\int_{|\xi |\leq 1}|h(\xi)|d \xi <\infty$ and $\int_{|\xi |>1}\frac{|h(\xi)|}{|\xi|}d \xi <\infty $.
How can I show this? I have no idea.

Comment: Apply Holder's inequality for both.